# $f(x,y)=2x+4y-x^2y^4$ has a critical point but no local extreme points.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I've to show that:
  $f(x,y)=2x+4y-x^2y^4$ has a critical point but no local extreme points.

> we mean by a critical point as that interior point where $f_x=f_y=0$ or the points where $f_x$ or $f_y$ fail to exist.

but I can't understand still what the question means?

Please help me out with what the question wants....

Comment: Do you know what a local extreme point is then?

Comment: @HansLundmark A local extreme point is a point in the interior of domain of $f$ where it attains maximum/minimum

Comment: That's not quite right... (It doesn't take the word *local* into account.)

Comment: @HansLundmark then what should be appropriate definition..kindly help me..

Comment: Should be in your textbook...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

The function has a critical point at:

$$\nabla f=\begin{pmatrix}2-2xy^4 \\ 4-4x^2y^3\end{pmatrix}=0$$

which gives $$(x,y)=(1,1)$$

Now look at the plot of the surface $z=f(x,y)$. Can you see why it isn't a local extreme point?

[image]

---

Now we can prove it algebraically.

Let's calculate the Hessian first:

$$H=\det \begin{pmatrix}-2y^4 & -8y^3 \\ -8xy^3 & -12x^2y^2 \end{pmatrix}\left.\right|_{(x,y)=(1,1)}=-40<0$$

Since the Hessian is smaller than $0$, $(1,1,5)$ is a saddle point, and not a local extremum.

Comment: The second derivative test is relevant here.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip, exactly. I first wanted the OP to discover it geometrically, and then support his answer with the second derivative test, but I will add it right now.

Comment: @RainiervanEs in the graph if I draw an arc from one direction it is looks local maximum whereas for other arc drawn it seems to be local minimum...thanks for the answer and graph of course....did you drew it in MATLAB.....

Comment: The graph comes from Wolfram Alpha.